# How to show images of links in profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I think this is a simple problem but I do not know how to phrase it to get a sample solution from a search engine.

Instead of allowing profile image uploads/gravatars on my website I would like to store links to images in the profile db table and embed those images in the profile show page view.

My initial thought is just to have a string url filed in the db. From there I do not know how rails will parse the string url and render the image.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a link to the image stored as a link on the profile, then in your view you could do something like this:

Add image_link to Profile model

In controller

```
def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  ....
end
```

In view

```
 <%= image_tag @profile.image_link %>
```

Comment: Quick question. When there is no image should it display the word "Asset"?

Comment: You could add conditional logic like this `<%= image_tag @profile.image_link if @profile.image_link %>` but it would probably be better to add a helper method that puts a default image up instead so

    def avatar(profile)
      profile.image_link||"http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-  default-avatar.png"
    end

Then change your view
`<%= image_tag avatar(profile) %>`